# The motivation of differential forms

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The motivation of differential form, I think, is created to deal with the integral on manifold. But in most textbooks, differential forms is introduced by some other knowledges about covectors, tensor products... But in the proof of most theorems of integral of Manifolds, I can't see many connections with covectors, tensor products... I can't see how they can be created together. Even, if the concept of differential form defined without introducing covectors and tensor products, will any problems happen?

Comment: Vectors are to vector fields as covectors are to differential one-forms.  I don't know that "most textbooks [on differential geometry]" introduce differential forms by first considering covectors/ tensor products, but if they do it's only to build up your knowledge of them a little more gradually and with this analogy to vector fields in mind.

Comment: @Bye_World thank you, I wonder, is covectors really useful in the integral on manifolds?

Comment: No.  Generally you use differential forms, not covectors.  Covectors are somewhat useful in algebra but only *pedagogically* in differential geometry.

Comment: @Bye_World is that necessary for integral on manifolds?

Comment: @6666: One can (and classically, I believe, did) introduce multivariable integration formally, using differential expressions $dx$, $dy$, etc., and declaring $dx\, dx = 0$, $dy\, dx = -dx\, dy$, etc., so that the fundamental theorem of calculus (i.e., the generalized Stokes theorem) works. Eventually, of course, one arrives at the question "What exactly _are_ $dx$, $dy$, etc.? Infinitesimal increments?" (In one variable, this question is a Math.SE staple.) One answer is, "They're coordinate differentials, a special type of covector field."

Comment: [...] So, if you like, covector-valued functions, a.k.a. differential forms, are a rigorous tool for constructing symbolic expressions that can be manipulated as required by multivariable differential and integral calculus.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang you just told me the motivation of covector field, and I am confused about the motivation of k-covector field, do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: @6666: Conceptually, a differential $k$-form is "an integrand suitable for a $k$-dimensional manifold". Algebraically, a $k$-form is a linear combination of $k$-fold wedge products of coordinate $1$-forms. Spivak's _Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. I_ discusses of the sense in which exterior calculus (differential forms, the exterior derivative, integration of forms, Stokes' theorem) is the only "natural" set of differentiation/integration operations on an arbitrary smooth manifold.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you.