# Why do books refer to $dx_1, \ldots, dx_n$ as differentials and also as covectors?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-forms

I'm studying differential forms. In Edwards Advanced Calculus, linear functionals are defined and we learn that each linear functional is a linear combination of the dual basis $ \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n$, where 
$$\gamma_i(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = v_i$$ 
($ i=1,\ldots, n$). Then he says that he will use the standard notation $ \gamma_i = dx_i$. He also calls the $ dx_i$ *differentials*.

I don't understand why or how *differentials* are related to the dual basis (aka covectors), and I don't understand how the dual basis is related to differentiation.

Maybe my confusion partly comes from high-school calculus, where the symbol $dx$ means an infinitesimal change in $x$.

Comment: The differential of a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a $1$-form $df$ called the *differential* of $f$, which is defined by $$df(X) = X \cdot f,$$ where $X$ is the directional derivative. In particular, $dx_i$ is the differential of the coordinate function $x_i$, and $$dx_i\left(\sum_i a_i \partial_{x_i}\right) = \left(\sum_i a_i \partial_{x_i}\right) x_i = a_i ,$$ i.e., $dx_i$ is the differential that picks out the $i$th component of its argument vector.

Comment: My comment under [The motivation of differential forms](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600845) may be of interest. (That question currently has no answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We have coordinate functions $x_i$ which are smooth functions $U \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x_i(a_1, \dots, a_n) = a_i$. The differential of the smooth map $x_i$ at $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is a linear map $dx_i : T_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}U \to T_{a_i}\mathbb{R}$; I should really write $(dx_i)_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}$ but I will just write $dx_i$ for the sake of brevity. As $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space, its tangent space at any point is canonically isomorphic to itself, so $T_{a_i}\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we can regard $dx_i$ as a linear map $T_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}U \to \mathbb{R}$, that is, as a linear functional or covector on the vector space $T_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}U$.

If you are new to this, keep in mind that vectors and covectors only make sense in a vector space. The vector space you are working with is not $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which will later be replaced by a manifold) but a tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The above description of differentials as covectors on a tangent space works in exactly the same way for manifolds.

Comment: Thanks. But what does $dx_i$ do? As I understand it, evaluated at a vector $v \in T_{(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}$, it gives us the directional derivative of $v$ in the $x_i$ direction. Is that the same as just giving us the $i$-th component of $v$?

Comment: Well, the tangent space $T_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}U$ is spanned by the vectors  $\partial_i$ tangent to the '$x_i$-directions'. So $v \in T_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}U$ can be written as $v = v_1\partial_1 + \dots + v_n\partial_n$ and $dx_i(v) = v_i$ which is the directional derivative of the function $x_i$ in the direction of the tangent vector $v$. To see this,  note that the directional derivative is $D_vx_i = \nabla x_i\cdot v = (0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)\cdot(v_1, \dots, v_n) = v_i$.